# How can I create meeting with 3 persons using Google Calendar's API?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am building a recruiting platform where an employer can book a meeting with a potential candidate. The owner of the website must be in this meeting.

So, basically, I would need to create a Google Meet with 3 invitations (us + 2 other people with email that are changing). Is there a way to achieve that using the Calendar API?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When creating Calendar Events with Google Meet using [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=en) method, you need to do the following:**

1. Set `conferenceDataVersion` parameter to 1

> Version 1 enables support for copying of `ConferenceData` as well as for creating new conferences using the `createRequest` field of `conferenceData`.

2. To create new conference details, use `createRequest` field of `conferenceData`. Set `conferenceSolutionKey type` to "hangoutsMeet" and set a random string for `requestId` in the request body.

**Sample conferenceData:**

```
"conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      },
      "requestId": "7qxalsvy0exxaje"
    }
  }
```

---

**If you want to send meeting invite to different people using [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?hl=en) method, you need to do the following:**

1. Set `sendUpdates` parameter to "all" to send notifications to all the guests invited.
2. Add event guests' using `attendees` properties in the request body.

**Sample:**

```
"attendees": [
    {
      "email": "user1@email.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "user2@email.com"
    }
  ],
```

---

**Sample Events.insert parameters and request body:**

[image]

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2021-01-01T04:00:00+08:00"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2021-01-01T03:00:00+08:00"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "email": "user1@email.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "user2@email.com"
    }
  ],
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "conferenceSolutionKey": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      },
      "requestId": "7qxalsvy0exxaje"
    }
  },
  "summary": "Sample Meeting"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**References:**

[Create Events using Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events?hl=en)

[Add video and phone conferences to events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events?hl=en#conferencing)

[Calendar API Reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference?hl=en)